# If a force equal and opposite to the electrostatic force is applied on a charge, how can the charge move in the electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

For measuring the electric potential difference between two oppositely charged plates A and B, a test charge q is moved from plate A to plate B.
My textbook says that the charge is kept in electrostatic equilibrium such that an equal and opposite force to the electrostatic force is applied on the charge to move it opposite to the electric field.

However, I don't understand how it is possible for a charge to move if it is acted upon by two equal and opposite forces.
My teacher said that the charge moves due to inertia, but I did not understand how, since the charge was initally moving towards the negative plate A.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A particle is moving with constant velocity and then you applied two forces equal and opposite on the particle such that they cancel each other. The particle will still move with that constant velocity.

Comment: The idea is to have an unbalanced force for a very brief period of time and then balance up the forces so that the object moves slowly with the acquired velocity. No acceleration,no net force ,no net increase in kinetic energy

Comment: @khaxan Thanks a lot. That cleared up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is to make sure the kinetic energy of the charge is the same at the end of its journey as that at the start.
This ensures that all the work done by the external force results in the change in electric potential energy of the charges.

One of the ways of achieving this is to have the charge move at constant speed.